# Why ufw deny(incoming) still allowes connections

Tags: firewall, ufw

I have enabled ufw. The is `ufw status verbose` output

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

But when I run nginx as
`docker run --name nginx -p 80:80 -d nginx`
I still can see nginx welcome page in the browser and nmap shows 80 port as open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Docker manages its own firewall rules via calling iptables directly. It will allow a port in the firewall when you expose it in your container. These are not visible in `ufw`.

Comment: What firewall would you recommend to use so that it works for all apps?

Comment: @ogbofjnr What do you mean? ufw seems to be just fine.

Comment: But all I have is docker containers, like rancher, and other workloads work in it. How do I control the opened ports then?

Comment: @ogbofjnr You could disable Docker's management of the firewall and allow ports in the firewall yourself, but then they would always be allowed, instead of only allowed when the relevant container is running.

Comment: Isn't ufw relying on iptables? Dont't the fw rules in ufw end up in iptables? 

For those using docker, they should use '**expose**' instead of '**ports**' when they do not want their ports to be reachable from outside/internet.

[See difference between ports and expose][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801772/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-compose-ports-vs-expose